# Ignore ad groups belonging to REMOVED campaigns with Adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

I am working on an adwords script to grab a list of all AD Groups which have a specified label, and are in the status PAUSED. My code is working, however I am running into one issue, which is that I am getting ad groups which belong to campaigns that have been REMOVED.

Is there any way to filter on **campaign status** as part of the adgroup service?

```
ad_group_service = client.GetService('AdGroupService', version='v201806')

selector = {
    'fields': ['Id', 'Name', 'Status', 'Labels'],
    'predicates': [
        {
        'field': 'Labels',
        'operator': 'EQUALS',
        'values': 'MY LABEL'
        },
        {
        'field': 'Status',
        'operator': 'EQUALS',
        'values': 'PAUSED'
        }
    ],
    'paging': {
    'startIndex': str(0),
    'numberResults': str(9999)
    }
}
adgroups = ad_group_service.get(selector)
```

Answer (score 0):

Through testing, I found out there is an undocumented field 'CampaignStatus' that can be used to achieve this.

```
selector = {
    'fields': ['Id', 'Name', 'Status', 'Labels'],
    'predicates': [
        {
        'field': 'Labels',
        'operator': 'EQUALS',
        'values': 'MY LABEL'
        },
        {
        'field': 'Status',
        'operator': 'EQUALS',
        'values': 'PAUSED'
        },
        {
        'field': 'CampaignStatus',
        'operator': 'NOT_EQUALS',
        'values': 'REMOVED'
        }
    ],
    'paging': {
    'startIndex': str(0),
    'numberResults': str(9999)
    }
}
```